# Local storage got cleared automatically after window.location.href change

Tags: jquery, ajax, local-storage

```
Ajax(){
...............
...............
success :function(response){
localStorage.setItem("token", response['token'])
 window.location.href="https://www.example.com/profiler/"
}

}
```

Above is my code snippet once I redirect to profile page local storage (token) row itself got removed .

Any one faced this issue or could you please help me to resolve?

Comment: Web storage doesn't clear itself. If you're seeing values not present when they used to be present, then either: A) You removed them in your code, B) The user removed them via devtools, C) You're looking in the wrong place, D) [Unlikely] You hit the storage limit. Re (C): Local storage is specific to the *origin* of the page. Origins include scheme (`http` vs `https`), host, and port. So `http://example.com` and `https://example.com` are different origins (different schemes). So are `https://example.com` and `https://www.example.com` (different host names).

Comment: we have tried with slow network and we can see the local storage is clearing when next (profile) page is loaded. And one more thing we noticed is local storage items persist in  the browsers which already visited profile page before.   And  service is working fine in local environment with out any issue

Comment: The speed of the network is irrelevant. Sounds like you're changing the origin to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder resolved  Thanks you. window.location.href=**https://www.example.com**/profiler/     Browser treated this as different origin so local storage is refreshed on location change . **window.location.href=/profiler/** - This worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Providing https: domain.com in window.location.href consider as  different origin, so local storage will be refreshed as the page loads.

`window.location.href="https://www.example.com/profiler/"`

**Use following instead :-**

`window.location.href="/profiler/"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.reload() if you want to reload the page.